# How to join all_tab_columns + all_cons_columns + all_constraints in Oracle

Tags: sql, database, oracle, left-join

Creating this table:

```sql
CREATE SEQUENCE my_seq;
CREATE TABLE mytable (
    id NUMBER(10) DEFAULT my_seq.nextval PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR2(10) NOT NULL,
    version FLOAT, 
    active CHAR, 
    updated DATE CONSTRAINT date_uk UNIQUE
)
```

I'm trying to join `all_tab_columns`, `all_cons_columns` and `all_constraints` tables (which are Oracle system tables, with information columns, etc).

If I join the first two:

```sql
SELECT at.owner, at.column_name, ac.constraint_name
FROM all_tab_columns at
LEFT JOIN all_cons_columns ac 
  ON (at.table_name = ac.table_name 
    AND at.owner = ac.owner 
    AND at.column_name = ac.column_name)
WHERE at.table_name = 'MYTABLE';
```

I get:

```
OWNER           COLUMN_NAME     CONSTRAINT_NAME
--------------- --------------- ---------------
TEST            ID              SYS_C008423
TEST            NAME            SYS_C008422
TEST            VERSION
TEST            ACTIVE
TEST            UPDATED         DATE_UK
```

When I join the later ones (`all_cons_columns` and `all_constraints`):

```sql
SELECT ac.owner, ac.column_name, ac.constraint_name, cc.constraint_type, cc.generated
FROM all_cons_columns ac
JOIN all_constraints cc 
  ON (ac.constraint_name = cc.constraint_name)
WHERE ac.table_name = 'MYTABLE';
```

I get:

```
OWNER           COLUMN_NAME     CONSTRAINT_NAME CONSTRAINT_TYPE GENERATED
--------------- --------------- --------------- --------------- ---------------
TEST            NAME            SYS_C008422     C               GENERATED NAME
TEST            ID              SYS_C008423     P               GENERATED NAME
TEST            UPDATED         DATE_UK         U               USER NAME
```

So far, so good.

But, when I try to join the 3 tables:

```sql
SELECT at.column_name, ac.constraint_name, cc.constraint_type, cc.generated
FROM all_tab_columns at
LEFT JOIN all_cons_columns ac 
  ON (at.table_name = ac.table_name 
    AND at.owner = ac.owner)
LEFT JOIN all_constraints cc 
  ON (ac.constraint_name = cc.constraint_name 
    AND ac.owner = cc.owner 
    AND ac.table_name = cc.table_name)
WHERE ac.table_name = 'MYTABLE';
```

I get this:

```
COLUMN_NAME     CONSTRAINT_NAME CONSTRAINT_TYPE GENERATED
--------------- --------------- --------------- ---------------
ID              SYS_C008422     C               GENERATED NAME
NAME            SYS_C008422     C               GENERATED NAME
VERSION         SYS_C008422     C               GENERATED NAME
ACTIVE          SYS_C008422     C               GENERATED NAME
UPDATED         SYS_C008422     C               GENERATED NAME
ID              SYS_C008423     P               GENERATED NAME
NAME            SYS_C008423     P               GENERATED NAME
VERSION         SYS_C008423     P               GENERATED NAME
ACTIVE          SYS_C008423     P               GENERATED NAME
UPDATED         SYS_C008423     P               GENERATED NAME
ID              DATE_UK         U               USER NAME

COLUMN_NAME     CONSTRAINT_NAME CONSTRAINT_TYPE GENERATED
--------------- --------------- --------------- ---------------
NAME            DATE_UK         U               USER NAME
VERSION         DATE_UK         U               USER NAME
ACTIVE          DATE_UK         U               USER NAME
UPDATED         DATE_UK         U               USER NAME
```

I'm expecting this:

```
COLUMN_NAM CONSTRAINT  CONSTRAINT_TYPE GENERATED
---------- ----------- --------------- --------------
ID         SYS_C008423 P               GENERATED NAME
NAME       SYS_C008422 C               USER NAME
VERSION    
ACTIVE     
UPDATED    DATE_UK     U               USER NAME
```

Where is the mistake?

Using `Oracle 12 XE`

**HOW TO TEST**
If you have docker:

```
docker run --name oracle_test \
  -e "ORACLE_PASSWORD=test" \
  -e "APP_USER=test" \
  -e "APP_USER_PASSWORD=test" \
  -p 1521:1521 \
  -d gvenzl/oracle-xe:21-slim
```

Then wait few minutes, and connect:

```
docker exec -it oracle_test sqlplus -l test/test@localhost:1521/XEPDB1
```

... and execute the `CREATE SEQUENCE and CREATE TABLE` statements.

### Reply to Connor McDonald

If I change the SQL to:

```sql
SELECT at.column_name, ac.constraint_name, cc.constraint_type, cc.generated
FROM all_tab_columns at
LEFT JOIN all_cons_columns ac ON (at.table_name = ac.table_name AND at.owner = ac.owner)
JOIN all_constraints cc ON (ac.constraint_name = cc.constraint_name AND ac.owner = cc.owner AND ac.table_name = cc.table_name)
WHERE ac.table_name = 'MYTABLE';
```

(Using `JOIN` on `cc` instead of `LEFT JOIN`):

Result:

```
COLUMN_NAME     CONSTRAINT_NAME CONSTRAINT_TYPE GENERATED
--------------- --------------- --------------- ---------------
ID              SYS_C008422     C               GENERATED NAME
NAME            SYS_C008422     C               GENERATED NAME
VERSION         SYS_C008422     C               GENERATED NAME
ACTIVE          SYS_C008422     C               GENERATED NAME
UPDATED         SYS_C008422     C               GENERATED NAME
ID              SYS_C008423     P               GENERATED NAME
NAME            SYS_C008423     P               GENERATED NAME
VERSION         SYS_C008423     P               GENERATED NAME
ACTIVE          SYS_C008423     P               GENERATED NAME
UPDATED         SYS_C008423     P               GENERATED NAME
ID              DATE_UK         U               USER NAME

COLUMN_NAME     CONSTRAINT_NAME CONSTRAINT_TYPE GENERATED
--------------- --------------- --------------- ---------------
NAME            DATE_UK         U               USER NAME
VERSION         DATE_UK         U               USER NAME
ACTIVE          DATE_UK         U               USER NAME
UPDATED         DATE_UK         U               USER NAME
```

Not what I'm expecting. I get the same result even if I change both `LEFT JOIN` to `JOIN`.

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code & example input; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. For SQL include DDL & tabular initialization code. For debug that includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. [ask] [Help] When you get a result you don't expect, pause your overall goal, chop to the 1st subexpression with unexpected result & say what you expected & why, justified by documentation. (Debugging fundamental.)

Comment: LEFT JOIN returns INNER JOIN rows UNION ALL unmatched left table rows extended by NULLs. Always know what INNER JOIN you want as part of an OUTER JOIN. After a LEFT JOIN a WHERE, INNER JOIN or HAVING that requires a right [sic] table column to be not NULL removes any rows with introduced NULLs, ie leaves only INNER JOIN rows, ie "turns OUTER JOIN into INNER JOIN". You have that. PS Use `select *` to see subexpression results. PS What is the relevanace of `ac inner join cc` to `at left join ac left join cc`? (Nb your final `where` makes the latter the same as `at inner join ac left join cc`.)

Comment: @philipxy I added the `How to test` and the `create table` in case someone needs it to try it

Comment: Please just give the SQL DML & DDL including table initialization in columns. Per my earlier comment & link. Posts should be self-contained.

Comment: @philipxy `all_tab_columns`, `all_cons_columns` and `all_constraints` tables are standard system information Oracle tables. I didn't created them. I only created `MYTEST` table.

Comment: I don't know why you commented that since it is already contradicted by my earlier comments. We need the exact contents of tables you ran with & we need to be able to run with exactly the same. PS Again: Say what you expect & why you expect it, justified by reference to authoritative documentation. Otherwise you're just asking us to rewrite yet another presentation for you to misunderstand, with no idea what your misconceptions are. And you're expecting us to walk through the code when you are not willing to. And only when pinned down & clearly phrased can problems be (re)searched. Good luck.

Comment: @philipxy I'm sorry, I believe my explanation is clear: One table is created without data. I'm trying to get that table schema information using the tables provided by Oracle. There is nothing else to do there. If you have Oracle or Docker you can reproduce my question very easily.

Comment: `all_***_columns` should obviously be joined by column name, not a table name only. You included this condition in your first part of the script, but did not in the overall script for unknown reason

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed my issue:

```sql
SELECT at.column_name, ac.constraint_name, cc.constraint_type, cc.generated
FROM all_tab_columns at
LEFT JOIN all_cons_columns ac 
  ON (at.owner = ac.owner
    AND at.table_name = ac.table_name 
    AND at.column_name = ac.column_name)
LEFT JOIN all_constraints cc 
  ON (ac.constraint_name = cc.constraint_name)    
WHERE at.table_name = 'MYTABLE';
```

I get:

```
COLUMN_NAME     CONSTRAINT_NAME CONSTRAINT_TYPE GENERATED
--------------- --------------- --------------- ---------------
NAME            SYS_C008422     C               GENERATED NAME
ID              SYS_C008423     P               GENERATED NAME
UPDATED         DATE_UK         U               USER NAME
VERSION
ACTIVE
```

I had two issues:

1. I was missing to join using `column_name` (not sure why I missed that).
2. `WHERE` clause was using a field from the `ac` table (intermediate), and it should have been `at` (the first one).

I hope this can help to anyone going through something similar.

Answer (score 0):

To satisfy

```
FROM all_cons_columns ac
JOIN all_constraints cc
```

you should be joining on OWNER, CONSTRAINT_NAME.  I'm not sure why you are using INDEX_NAME here.

Comment: I added to the question what happen when I change the second `LEFT JOIN` into `JOIN`. I'm not sure if that is what you meant, as your answer is not that clear. Can you add how the SQL should look like? The reason I'm using `index_name` is because for some reason oracle is adding a constraint in `name` with the same name as `id`, which is strange to me.

Comment: The initial column width was making me believe that `name` and `id` had the same constraint name, but they are not. So I should use `constraint_name`. I will update the question.